# XML Literals in VB.NET Code don't seem work with #if statements

Tags: vb.net, xml-literals

I have a vb.net project that uses an XML literal to configure the user interface navigation bar.  The code looks something like this and has been working for many years.

```
Private ReadOnly _actionTreeXml As XElement =
<nodes>
    <node key="any" name="Top">
        <node key="log" name="***LOGIN***" type="everybody"></node>
        <node key="op" name="Home" ctrl="uiHomePage" type="mfg"></node>
        <node key="barcode" name="Barcode Entry" ctrl="EditMfgEntry" type="mfg"></node>
        <node key="wip" name="Work in Progress" ctrl="QueryWIP" type="mfg"></node>
        <node key="readme" name="Version Info" type="everybody"></node>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

I recently needed to have two builds of the project that differ slightly (don't want to pay for library code for many users).  So I have one build where I #if out all the ui tools related to the barcode.  This works great everwhere except in XML literals like this

```
#if USE_BAR_CODE=1
<node key="barcode" name="Barcode Entry"    ctrl="EditMfgEntry" type="mfg">  </node>
#end if
```

If I set USE_BAR_CODE to 0 I still get the xml literal inside the #if block, but everywhere in my code where I #if'ed regular VB source the code was not compiled.

This leads me to believe that the compliation process handles xml literals BEFORE #if statements.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be not the solution at all, but as proverb says "A bad bush is better than the open field".

The main idea is to use processing instruction node. If element has processing instruction above it, then skip it, otherwise include it. This way you can control the "inclusiveness" of that element.

**1)  First, create extension method:**

```
Module XmlExtentions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Function Filter(root_node As IEnumerable(Of XElement)) As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        Return root_node.First().Elements().Where(
            Function(e)
                If e.PreviousNode Is Nothing Then Return True
                Return e.PreviousNode.NodeType <> Xml.XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction
            End Function)
    End Function
End Module
```

**2. Query our XML:**

```
Dim _actionTreeXml As XElement =
    <nodes>
        <node key="any" name="Top">
            <node key="log" name="***LOGIN***" type="everybody"></node>
            <node key="op" name="Home" ctrl="uiHomePage" type="mfg"></node>
            <?Skip-Element?>
            <node key="barcode" name="Barcode Entry" ctrl="EditMfgEntry" type="mfg"></node>
            <node key="wip" name="Work in Progress" ctrl="QueryWIP" type="mfg"></node>
            <node key="readme" name="Version Info" type="everybody"></node>
        </node>
    </nodes>

Dim elements = _actionTreeXml.<node>.Filter()
'// Do something...
elements.ToList().ForEach(Sub(e) Console.WriteLine(e))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that solves the problem because I can't conditionally define which the skip the node in the xml literal... However, I *could* setup a list of excluded nodes in code (e.g. create a list and have exclude.add("BarCode") calls), and check that list of exclusions when I build my UI.  That will work.  Not great because I need to have run time code to do this...a bad bush indeed.

Comment: @Hucker *I can't conditionally define...*  Beg your pardon, but in your question you wanted to do this very thing...

Comment: The previous answer says you can't conditionally exclude a part of the tree, only the whole thing.

Comment: @Hucker I guess, you have [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: `you can't conditionally exclude a part of the tree`, very true indeed.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I offered some solution how to replace `#If` with processing instruction. May be I don't get something?

Comment: I'm not sure it is an X/Y problem.  I did not understand that the #if machinery works fundamentally differently than that of C (which was the mental model I was using).  The first answer makes it clear I was wrong.  The right answer is you can't #if inside of literals, if you want to not repeat large blocks of code you will need to create run time machinery (that can have #if constructs) to filter the XML literal.

Comment: @Hucker Yes, you can't have conditional constructs in XML, but I offered solution when you can skip certain elements if it's previous node is processing instruction. I *do* understand that this may be not the solution at all (since I don't what you retrieve from XML and, generally, how you process it), that's why I warned about it in my answer.

Comment: I used your input as inspiration for my solution.  I named my nodes   "xxxx-bar" and when I render my UI I filter by nodes that have "-bar" in their names.  This filter is one line of code that is conditionally compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, you can't use directives like this in literals. Under the hood, the behavior is the same as the `If, Then and Else` statements. You can't put those directly in line the way you are, you have to wrap the code block to tell the compiler what to compile versus run time compile like the standard `If, Then and Else` statements. The statements within a conditional compilation block must be complete logical statements. For example, you cannot conditionally compile only the attributes of literals, functions etc...

So a quick solution is below to either include the node or not include it. This was tested as well and works just fine.

```
#If USE_BAR_CODE = 1 Then
    Private ReadOnly _actionTreeXml As XElement = <nodes>
                                                      <node key="any" name="Top">
                                                          <node key="log" name="***LOGIN***" type="everybody"></node>
                                                          <node key="op" name="Home" ctrl="uiHomePage" type="mfg"></node>
                                                          <node key="barcode" name="Barcode Entry" ctrl="EditMfgEntry" type="mfg"></node>
                                                          <node key="wip" name="Work in Progress" ctrl="QueryWIP" type="mfg"></node>
                                                          <node key="readme" name="Version Info" type="everybody"></node>
                                                      </node>
                                                  </nodes>
#Else
    Private ReadOnly _actionTreeXml As XElement = <nodes>
                                                      <node key="any" name="Top">
                                                          <node key="log" name="***LOGIN***" type="everybody"></node>
                                                          <node key="op" name="Home" ctrl="uiHomePage" type="mfg"></node>                                                          
                                                          <node key="wip" name="Work in Progress" ctrl="QueryWIP" type="mfg"></node>
                                                          <node key="readme" name="Version Info" type="everybody"></node>
                                                      </node>
                                                  </nodes>


#End If
```

Comment: @JohnyL please explain? VS does this for me as well as my two extensions...

Comment: I don't believe it  Did you try to press `Enter` before `<nodes>`? :)

Comment: Depends on what version of VS a user is using, automatic code reformatting was introduced in 2015 for two steps; newline and formatting... Also ReSharper as well as CodeFormatter puts it back in-line, VS doesn't on my version.

Comment: Also using a directive like above (in the first condition), VS doesn't format the code when entered is pressed, it does indeed drop to a newline, but doesn't format the code :). Is there anything else I may be of help?

Comment: No, thanks) Your explanation is good! I offered another solution, but it's hard to name it a solution.  But at least I tried!

Comment: As a C programmer I don't like this answer :)  An important aspect of the conditional compliation is preventing the dupication of code.  My actual code block is MUCH larger than what is shown in my snippet.  Making duplicating the entire tree to disable 3  lines of code is a poor solution.